# JPA if I have an entity that is being used as a composite key, does the cascade also form part of the composite key?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My question is does the cascaded class form part of the composite key? So for example if I am querying by Question answer will the result also consider the fields inside the cascaded class?

```
@Embeddable
public class QuestionAnswer implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "QUESTION_ID", nullable = false)
    /** The id of the question this answer applies to. */
    private Long questionId;
    @Column(name = "ANSWER_ID", nullable = false)
    /** The answer id. */
    private Long answerId;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARTICIPANTS_REF_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARTICIPANT_REF_ID")
    /** The participant that is involved in this answer.*/
    private ParticipantReference participant
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTICIPANTS_REF")
public class ParticipantReference implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "someIdGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "someIdGenerator", sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "PARTICIPANT_REF_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private long age;

    @Column(name = "GENDER")
    private String gender;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer after comparing the hash of different objects is Yes the cascade class does form part of the composite key.